# Take Profit should be executed x times. - listed Attempts so far have failed

Tags: pine-script

[soldwith0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUdyq.png)   [tradingviewlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfnGr.png)
The Take Profit should be executed x times. each with the same number of position closures. A set percentage should continue to run until another exit condition is true at some point.

My failed attempts are listed under if strategy.position_size > 0 // 734 and the other sections.

- /734 <<<<< Condition is repeated endlessly, but TP is only taken once, even though it is always shown in the trading view.
- Condition with 100% closure is executed and also displayed correctly in Tradingview
- The idea is that when TP1 is closed, we should continue with TP2. If TP2 is closed, TP3 should continue, etc. The percentages that should continue to run should then be closed by some other SL/exit. Unfortunately no effect here either. or endless continuation

  ```
    //@version=5 
    strategy('EMA-Cross', overlay=true, initial_capital=100, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=100, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.075, pyramiding=10)


    // EMA
    var G_ema_cross = " EMA-Cross.........................................."

    ema_len1 = input.int(title="EMA Kurzperiode", defval=21, group=G_ema_cross)
    ema_len2 = input.int(title="EMA Kurzperiode", defval=32, group=G_ema_cross)

    src = close//input.source(title="Source", defval=close, group=G_ema_cross)
    htf_ma1 = ta.ema(src, ema_len1)
    htf_ma2 = ta.ema(src, ema_len2)
    plot(htf_ma1, color=color.green, title='EMA1')

    ema_mult = input.float(1.0, minval=0, step=0.01, maxval=50,title="EMA Abweichung", group=G_ema_cross) 
    ema_len1_dev = ema_mult * ta.stdev(src, ema_len1) 

    emaupper = htf_ma1 + ema_len1_dev 
    emalower = htf_ma1 - ema_len1_dev 

    plot(emaupper, color=color.new(color.silver, 0), title='Upper') 
    plot(emalower, color=color.new(color.silver, 0), title='Lower') 


    ema_long = ta.crossunder(htf_ma1, htf_ma2)



    var G_ausstiege = " AUSSTIEGE.........................................." 
    U3TP = input(true, title='TP über Upper / unter Lower', group=G_ausstiege)
    priceU3TP = high
    priceL3TP = low



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Version 734: U4 TPs werden nicht richtig ausgeführt.
    // Es wurde öfter gekauft, wie angegeben, aber nur 2x TP von 6 genommen. - Weitere TPs werden aber in TV noch angezeigt.
    // Pionex zeigt Käufe an. Aber Verkäufe nur 2x. Und weitere Verkäufe sind mit 0TP
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    TPs = input(6, title='Anzahl TakeProfits', group=G_ausstiege)
    weiterlaufen = input(10, title='X% sollen weiterlaufen', group=G_ausstiege)
    TPsQty = (100-weiterlaufen) / TPs


    U3TP_cond = priceU3TP > emaupper and U3TP

    var closeU3TP1 = false
    var closeU3TP2 = false
    var closeU3TP3 = false
    var closeU3TP4 = false


    // Strategieanweisung Long 
    if ema_long
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)


    if strategy.position_size > 0
        // //734 <<<<< Condition is repeated endlessly, but TP is only taken once, even though it is always shown in the trading view.
        if U3TP_cond
            strategy.close("Long", "U-TP", qty_percent=TPsQty)

        // // //734 nur ein tp <<<<<<<<<<<<< Condition with 100% closure is executed and also displayed correctly in Tradingview
        // if U3TP_cond
        //     strategy.close("Long", "U-TP", qty_percent=100)

        // // The idea is that when TP1 is closed, we should continue with TP2. If TP2 is closed, TP3 should continue, etc
        // // The percentages that should continue to run should then be closed by some other SL/exit.
        // // Unfortunately no effect here either. or endless continuation
        // if U3TP_cond// and not closeU3TP1
        //     strategy.close("Long", "U-TP1", qty_percent=TPsQty)
        //     closeU3TP1 := true

        // if U3TP_cond and closeU3TP1 and not closeU3TP2
        //     strategy.close("Long", "U-TP2", qty_percent=TPsQty)
        //     closeU3TP2 := true

        // if U3TP_cond and closeU3TP1 and closeU3TP2 and not closeU3TP3
        //     strategy.close("Long", "U-TP3", qty_percent=TPsQty)
        //     closeU3TP3 := true






    // if strategy.position_size > 0 and upper2StopL
    //     strategy.exit("longU1", "Long", stop=upper2)
  ```